# Manipulating Import-Csv objects and exporting to text file line by line

Tags: arrays, powershell, csv, import-csv, export-csv

I'm basically trying to build a routine that reads a named folder directory, builds a CSV file, then reads in that CSV file, manipulates some of the properties to split data into new columns, exports that to another CSV.

This I have achieved with the following code:

```cs
$Folder = Read-Host 'Please enter a folder path'
$File = Read-Host 'Please enter a filename'
$OutputFile = $Folder + '\' + $File + '.csv'
$SplitFile = $Folder + '\' + $File + '_Split.csv'
$CopyDir = $Folder + '\WantedDocs\'

Get-ChildItem $Folder -Recurse -Include *.* |
    select Directory, FullName, Name |
    Export-Csv -Delimiter ',' -NoTypeInformation $OutputFile

$a = Import-Csv $OutputFile 
$values = $a.Name.Split("_") 
$a | Add-Member 'CliCode' -NotePropertyValue $values[3]
$a | Add-Member 'CopyDir' -NotePropertyValue $CopyDir

$a | Select Directory, FullName, Name, CliCode, CopyDir |
    Export-Csv -Delimiter ',' -NoTypeInformation $SplitFile
```

Excuse me if my terminology isn't right, but I am now looking to build a batch file full of `xcopy` commands, using item values from the properties.

```
xcopy 'C:\Test\OriginalDocs\A\file1_A_A_12345678.txt' 'C:\Test\WantedDocs\*' /Y
```

When you use `Import-Csv` and assign it to a variable, that variable contain various properties, with each property containing an array of values taken from each line in the CSV file.

In my example the variable `$a` has properties called "Directory", "FullName" and "Name", the headers of the 3 columns in my CSV file.

If my CSV file contains these lines:

```
"Directory","FullName","Name"
"C:\Test\OriginalDocs\A","C:\Test\OriginalDocs\A\file1_A_A_12345678.txt","file1_A_A_12345678.txt"
"C:\Test\OriginalDocs\B","C:\Test\OriginalDocs\B\file2_B_B_43534554.txt","file1_B_B_43534554.txt"
```

The Directory property would be an array of 2 items: "C:\Test\OriginalDocs\A" and "C:\Test\OriginalDocs\B\"

The FullName property would be an array of 2 items: "C:\Test\OriginalDocs\A\file1_A_A_12345678.txt" and "C:\Test\OriginalDocs\B\file2_B_B_43534554.txt"

The Name property would be an array of 2 items: "file1_A_A_12345678.txt" and "file2_B_B_43534554.txt"

What I want to know is how would I be able to select all [0] items in the array for each property and build the `xcopy` command

e.g. if I do this:

```
$xc1 = "xcopy '"
$xc2 = $a.FullName
$xc3 = "' '"
$xc4 = $a.CopyDir
$xc5 = $a.CliCode
$xc6 = "\*' /Y"
$xcopy = $xc1 + $xc2 + $xc3 + $xc4 + $xc5+ $xc6
```

The resulting `$xcopy` variable contains all array vales

e.g. for the example above the `xcopy` variable ends up with the value:

```
xcopy 'C:\Test\OriginalDocs\A\file1_A_A_12345678.txt C:\Test\OriginalDocs\B\file2_B_B_43534554.txt' 'C:\Test\OriginalDocs\WantedDocs\ C:\Test\OriginalDocs\WantedDocs\12345678 43534554\*' /Y
```

What I want to achieve is to effectively do this with the [0] array values from each selected property:

```
$xc1 = "xcopy '"
$xc2 = $a.FullName[0]
$xc3 = "' '"
$xc4 = $a.CopyDir[0]
$xc5 = $a.CliCode[0]
$xc6 = "\*' /Y"
$xcopy = $xc1 + $xc2 + $xc3 + $xc4 + $xc5+ $xc6
```

Write the `$xcopy` variable to the text file (using `Add-Content` I believe)

Then do the same with the [1] array values:

```
$xc1 = "xcopy '"
$xc2 = $a.FullName[1]
$xc3 = "' '"
$xc4 = $a.CopyDir[1]
$xc5 = $a.CliCode[1]
$xc6 = "\*' /Y"
$xcopy = $xc1 + $xc2 + $xc3 + $xc4 + $xc5+ $xc6
```

And so on until all items in the arrays are dealt with.

So producing a text/batch file with a line for each item in the arrays i.e. all the [0], all the [1] etc.

Using my example above I'd get a text file like below.

```
xcopy 'C:\Test\OriginalDocs\A\file1_A_A_12345678.txt' 'C:\Test\OriginalDocs\WantedDocs\12345678\*' /Y
xcopy 'C:\Test\OriginalDocs\B\file2_B_B_43534554.txt' 'C:\Test\OriginalDocs\WantedDocs\43534554\*' /Y
```

I've been looking at `foreach` and `ForEach-Object` but so far I've not found anything that works for my needs.  Maybe it can't be done?

Comment: It's a long read, but at first glance, you need to 1) add a space between `-NoteProperty` and `Value`. 2) CHECK, CHECK, DOUBLE-CHECK any user input before you use it. 3) use the `Join-Path` cmdlet when combining folder and file names instead of hard-coding the backslash. Then.. why use `XCOPY` instead of simply loop over all rows in the CSV, create the path for that specific file and do a `Copy-Item` on that?

Comment: You really should read what a [mcve] is, otherwise you'll loose your audience fast. [How-to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Hi @Theo Thanks for the reply. I need to create new directories in the target directory where the files would be copied to.  As I understand it, Copy-Item will not create new folders if the source items are files.  I got an error when I tried this:  $b = Import-Csv $SplitFile

Foreach ($Row in $b)
{
    $OriginalFile = $($Row.FullName)
    $CopyFile = $CopyDir + $($Row.CliCode)
 Copy-Item $OriginalFile -Destination $CopyFile -Force -Recurse
}

Comment: To execute "text" use `Invoke-Expression`. But I would rather use a pure powershell solution without `xcopy`.

Comment: Yes, you need to make sure the path for the file exists. You do that with `Test-Path` and `New-Item` cmdlets.

Answer (score 0):

To work line by line use `foreach`:

```
foreach ($Line in $a){ DoSomethingLikeCopy $Line.FullName to "$CopyDir\$($Line.CliCode)"   }
```

Instead of `XCopy` use `New-Item` to create a new textfile with the Value of the old file or to create the folder for the new Item:

```
Get-Content -Path 'C:\Test\OriginalDocs\A\file1_A_A_12345678.txt' -raw | New-Item -Path 'C:\Test\OriginalDocs\WantedDocs\12345678\file1_A_A_12345678.txt' -Force
```

or

```
New-Item -Path'C:\Test\OriginalDocs\WantedDocs\12345678\*' -ItemType directory
```

Answer (score 0):

It's pointless to export data to a CSV that you're reading back right away. Simply use a pipeline. Also, `xcopy` is an external command and can be run directly from PowerShell, so there's no need to have PowerShell create a batch file first.

This should be all you need:

```
$Folder = Read-Host 'Please enter a folder path'
Get-ChildItem $Folder -Recurse | ForEach-Object {
    $clicode = $_.BaseName.Split("_")[-1]
    & xcopy $_.FullName "${Folder}\WantedDocs\${clicode}\*" /y
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you indeed want output CSV files for every step of the way, you can do something like this:

```
# YOU NEED TO ADD CODE FOR CHECKING THE USER INPUT
# What I'm doing here is very rudimentary..
do {
    $Folder = Read-Host 'Please enter a folder path'
} while (-not (Test-Path -Path $Folder -PathType Container))

$File = Read-Host 'Please enter a filename (no extension)'


# at the very least sanitize the given filename, and get only the Name without Extension
$BaseName   = [System.IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($File)
$OutputFile = Join-Path -Path $Folder -ChildPath ($BaseName + '.csv')
$SplitFile  = Join-Path -Path $Folder -ChildPath ($BaseName + '_Split.csv')
$CopyDir    = Join-Path -Path $Folder -ChildPath 'WantedDocs'

# collect the files and get the properties Directory, FullName and Name
$a = Get-ChildItem $Folder -Recurse -Include *.* -File | Select-Object Directory,FullName,Name

# write the first CSV file:
$a | Export-Csv -Path $OutputFile -Delimiter ',' -NoTypeInformation

# redefine the collection to add extra properties CliCode, CopyDir and Result
$a = $a | Select-Object *,CliCode,CopyDir,Result
# loop through the collection
$a | ForEach-Object {
    # the automatic variable $_ is a single object in the collection
    # get the CliCode from the Name property:
    # if the filename is "file1_A_A_12345678.txt", the CliCode will be "12345678"
    if ($_.Name -match '([^_.]+)\..*$') {
        $cliCode   = $matches[1]
        $targetDir = Join-Path -Path $CopyDir -ChildPath $cliCode
        $_.CliCode = $cliCode       # example: "12345678"
        $_.CopyDir = $targetDir     # example: "C:\Test\WantedDocs\12345678"

        # copy the file, but create the target folder first if this does not exist
        if (-not (Test-Path -Path $targetDir -PathType Container)) {
            New-Item -Path $targetDir -ItemType Directory | Out-Null
        }
        Copy-Item -Path $_.FullName -Destination $targetDir
        $_.Result = "OK"
    } 
    else {
        # show the error and add "Failure" to the result property
        Write-Warning "Skipped file '$_.FullName'. Reason: CliCode not found"
        $_.Result = "Failure"
    }

}

# output the results of the copy as CSV file
$a | Export-Csv -Path $SplitFile -Delimiter ',' -NoTypeInformation
```

When done, the files are copied to the new locations and you'll have two CSV files:
The first 'Something.csv' **before** the copy:

```
"Directory","FullName","Name"
"D:\Test\OriginalDocs\A","D:\Test\OriginalDocs\A\file1_A_A_12345678.txt","file1_A_A_12345678.txt"
"D:\Test\OriginalDocs\B","D:\Test\OriginalDocs\B\file2_B_B_43534554.txt","file2_B_B_43534554.txt"
```

and the second 'Something_Split.csv' **after** the copy:

```
"Directory","FullName","Name","CliCode","CopyDir","Result"
"D:\Test\OriginalDocs\A","D:\Test\OriginalDocs\A\file1_A_A_12345678.txt","file1_A_A_12345678.txt","12345678","D:\Test\OriginalDocs\WantedDocs\12345678","OK"
"D:\Test\OriginalDocs\B","D:\Test\OriginalDocs\B\file2_B_B_43534554.txt","file2_B_B_43534554.txt","43534554","D:\Test\OriginalDocs\WantedDocs\43534554","OK"
```

The 'Result' column will display **Failure** if the filename did not contain a CliCode in the name, otherwise **OK**

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all the replies.  Using a combination of what has been advised, I now have the solution I need.

Many thanks for all the assistance.  I've added an if else section to the file processing because I would only be interested in files that follow a specific naming convention (xx_xx_xx_clicode_xxx.ext). This is for a specific project where I'll be supplied with 1000s of files, most of which should follow the naming convention.  So I'm checking the number of elements in the $values variable array to make sure it has at least 4 values (i.e. [3] exists as a value). Where it doesn't exist I'm writing the filename out to a log file.

This is the completed solution:

```
do {
    $Folder = Read-Host 'Please enter a folder path'
} while (-not (Test-Path -Path $Folder -PathType Container))

$File = Read-Host 'Please enter a filename (no extension)'

$OutputFile = Join-Path -Path $Folder -ChildPath ($File + '.csv')
$SplitFile = Join-Path -Path $Folder -ChildPath ($File + '_Split.csv')
$CopyDir = Join-Path $Folder -ChildPath 'WantedDocs'

$logfile = "log.txt"
$log = Join-Path -Path $Folder -ChildPath $logfile

Get-ChildItem $Folder -Recurse -Include *.* | select Directory,FullName,Name | Export-Csv -Delimiter ',' -NoTypeInformation $OutputFile

$a = Import-Csv $OutputFile 

$a | Add-Member 'CopyDir' -NotePropertyValue $CopyDir

$a | Select Directory,FullName,Name,CopyDir | Export-Csv -Delimiter ',' -NoTypeInformation $SplitFile

Foreach ($Row in $a)
{
    $values = $Row.Name.split("_") 
    If ($values.Count -gt 3)
    {
        $tempfile = Join-Path -Path $CopyDir -ChildPath $values[3]
        $OriginalFile = $($Row.FullName)
        $CopyFile = $tempfile
        New-Item -ItemType directory -Path $tempfile -Force
        Copy-Item $OriginalFile -Destination $CopyFile -Force -Recurse
    }
    Else
    {
        Add-Content $log $Row.Name
    }
}

Write-Output "Finished"
```

Many thanks once again. Much appreciated.